# Connect master report and subreport - passing list of objects to subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using the *iReport 4.5.1* and I've faced a problem with connecting master report and subreport.

I have two objects:

- **Account** (accountID, date, listOfParagraphs) - all fields are defined in master report;
- **Paragraph** (account, paragraphNo, someObject) - all fields defined in subreport(*stavke.jrxml*).

The ***listOfParagraphs*** is defined as ***`java.util.List<Paragraph>`*** (List of objects) and I want to pass it to subreport.

I've defined this subreport's properties in master report:

- **Subreport expression**: *stavke.jasper*
- **Expression class**: *java.lang.String*
- **Connection type**: *Use a datasource expression*
- **Datasource expression**:

```java
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfParagraphs})
```

I get this error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file : stavke.jasper
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:101)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(JRLoader.java:253)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:301)
    .....
```

I've tried so hard about this, but i can't solve it.

Can someone help me, please?

@Vyccus (edited)

I've changed paths a bit:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Documents and Settings\\D\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Project\\subreport\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

and

```
<subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="42" width="555" height="100"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{ls})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "stavke.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

Now i get this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java:706)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:394)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:368)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2036)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:613)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Please make sure that
i)   stavke.jasper file does exist. 
ii)  If so, then is it on the right location ?
iii) Also check, is it readable ?

Comment: Yes, stavke.jrxml exist in the same folder as main.jrxml. Anything else i should check?

Comment: can you add how you're setting the path of your *stavke.jasper*?

Comment: I think you should specify absolute path. is this a webapp? or a desktop app?

Comment: @Vyccus: I have edited post above and inserted paths.

Comment: @Damian: It is a desktop app.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using the same version in both *iReport* and *JasperReport* jar?

Comment: Another thing that I have to ask you. Are you aware of that this report will only work in your machine?

Comment: I don't have problems with reports witch don't contain subreports. They are generated and everything is fine. Only report with subreport is critical.
Yes, i am aware that that - absolute path. Above all, i need to make it work and then i will try to set relative path.

Comment: I was doing some research and I found something that relates this problem with a missing file, in this case the SubReport file. Please add a try-catch block in order to capture a JRException where you're filling the report, this might show us a more accurate trace.

Comment: This all exceptions above are catching JRException in try-catch block. I've allready surrounded it with try-catch. It brakes here: JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, ds);

Comment: yeah, when it try to fill your subreport it can't find the file I guess. You could do a test to prove that by passing your *.jasper* as a parameter and then using it as your subreport, this would vanish away all our doubts

Comment: I've created a chat because we can't talk that much here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15711/jasperreport-passing-a-subreport-through-a-parameter

Comment: I can't chat because i have reputation below 20.

Comment: Then I'll write a answer explaining this to you

Comment: @Gopinagh... Your comments helped me solve a problem that I was having with subreport. I had to add the path as <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["./Sub_Report.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Code:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//if you want this to be compiled in runtime

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(your JRXMLReport path file here);
JasperReport subReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(your JRXMLSubReport path file here);

//you can notice that there're a lot of overloaded mathods to compile it, you can choose
//what is better in your case

//if you want to use the complied file *.jasper
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(new File("filenameReport.jasper"));

JasperReport subReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(new File("filenameSubReport.jasper"));


//Then you add your subReport in your parameter Map
parameters.put("SUBREPORT_JASPER_FILE", subReport);

JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters,
                new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(yourList));
```

JRXML:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_JASPER_FILE" class="java.lang.Object"/> // you can also create this using the option in your iReport


<subreport>
    <reportElement uuid="c62c7896-f37a-4e76-a4cb-70e2545947da" style="Style" x="279" y="0" width="296" height="15"/>
       <dataSourceExpression>
            <![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{yourSubList})]]>  
       </dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_JASPER_FILE}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

I think that way you'll accomplish what you're trying to do

Comment: I get this:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location : net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport@19f36d9
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(JRLoader.java:262)
...
I think that i'm close... When i putt on comments //param.put("SUBREPORT_JASPER_FILE", subReport); report gets generated, but there is no subreport section whitch should be generated from passed list.

Comment: This exception is happening here: JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(l)); When parameter is not set, report shows, but without subreport.

Comment: I can't copy it because comment's size. Rest:
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:301)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:327)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:263)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2036)

Comment: Same thing... JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport@19f36d9 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(JRLoader.java:2‌​62) ......

Comment: please, try another test: new File("your path here").exists(); and see whether the return is true.

Comment: I've tested here all those approaches that i passed to you and all of them worked. This is really weird and can be tons of things, so I will show you another approach and if it still not working you would better show me your JRXML and maybe more of your java code.

write this before your "loadObjectLocation":
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(yourPath);
   BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis); 

then you change your "loadObjectLocation" to: 

JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(bufferedInputStream);

Comment: Result is: master report is generated, but without subreport... Whitch is the easiest way to send you some code?

Comment: i'll make some tests on it in my lunch time, hope I come back with an answer.

Comment: Everything is working great now! Thank you very much Vyccus! It turns out that my jasperreports.jar is corrupted in some way. One more thing i like to ask you... When there is a new jasperrepots.jar version, is it a good practice to download the same version of iReport? For example: Now i have jasperreport-4.6.jar and iReport 4.6. I've read that it may cause problem, and i think that this was the cause of my problem...
You can delete links, i will do that too. Thanks again!

Comment: By the way... I was using jasperreports-4.0.2.jar, and iReport 4.5.1.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Yes, it probably was your problem and you always have to use the same version in order to avoid compatibility problems.

Comment: This example helped me to find out how to add a subreport with a list. Thank you very much.