# What Jasper Studio elements are best suited for a given template

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a pre-processed A4 paper:

[image]

I need to fill it with objects (marked first object with red rectangle) in order to get this:
[image]

But I can have a collection of `0`,`1`,`50` objects (always `8` objects per page). I was thinking about either `subreport` or `list`, but I am new in jasper studio so I'm not sure which way will be best suited in my case. Could you give me some suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, you can use subreport or table or list.  Maybe the subreport is the best choice in case all lists are the same

Comment: could you give me a hint on the flow ? for now, I was trying to pass a collection of objects (just to get acquainted) to subreport according to below question. But it just doesn't work for me. I've spent so much time, but it just fails. I am doing something wrong but instead of creating a new question I thought I can try here first.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063947/connect-master-report-and-subreport-passing-list-of-objects-to-subreport